# Add data into Hive external table

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, hive, amazon-kinesis

I am following an tutorial on streaming data from Amazon Kinesis to Hive on Amazon EMR. I was successfully able to do this with a Hive Internal table, but when I try the same with external table I run into a weird EOF error. I have not used STORED BY and STORED AS together before, and I think this could be the issue. I used the IBM guide (http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPT3X_2.1.1/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.bigsql.doc/doc/bsql_create_table.html) to verify that they can be used together.

Here is the code I am using to build the hive external table.

```
DROP TABLE apachelog;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE apachelog (
  host STRING,
  IDENTITY STRING,
  USER STRING,
  TIME STRING,
  request STRING,
  STATUS STRING,
  SIZE STRING,
  referrer STRING,
  agent STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  "input.regex" = "([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (-|\\[[^\\]]*\\]) ([^ \"]*|\"[^\"]*\") ([0-9]*) ([0-9]*) ([^ \"]*|\"[^\"]*\") ([^ \"]*|\"[^\"]*\")"
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE
STORED BY
'com.amazon.emr.kinesis.hive.KinesisStorageHandler'
TBLPROPERTIES("kinesis.stream.name"="AccessLogStream")
LOCATION 's3://<bucket-name>/AccessLogStreamOP/';
```

And here is the error:

```
hive> source create_access_log.hql;
OK
Time taken: 0.464 seconds
FAILED: ParseException line 19:0 missing EOF at 'STORED' near 'TEXTFILE'
```

Answer (score 1):

In accordance with [Hive LangaugeManual DDL](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL)

```
  [
    [ROW FORMAT row_format] [STORED AS file_format]
    | STORED BY 'storage.handler.class.name' [WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (...)]  
  ]
```

you may use either ROW FORMAT or STORED BY clause and WITH SERDEPROPERTIES should follow STORED BY